# Run org-babel-tangle inside Org Src buffer

Tags: org-mode, restructuredtext, literate-programming, org-babel

I was wondering if there is a way to run `org-babel-tangle` on the parent file when I'm on a `Org Src` buffer.

The workflow is I'm editing a (reStructuredText) source code block in a `Org Src` buffer, but from time to time I want to export the code blocks to an `.rst` file so I can compile it and see the output.

Currently I have to constantly go back to the original `.org` buffer to run `org-babel-tangle` - it would be great if I can just run it inside the `Org Src` buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Surprised this one didn't have an answer already! I was just searching before I coded this one up myself... Anyway here's what I'm using:

```lisp
(defun alec-tangle-from-org-src-buffer ()
  "Tangle the file being currently edited in an Org Src buffer."
  (interactive)
  (when-let ((org-src-minor-mode-p (member 'org-src-mode local-minor-modes))
             (file-buf org-src-source-file-name))
    ;; save-window-excursion 
    (call-interactively #'org-edit-src-save)
    (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect file-buf)
      (call-interactively #'org-babel-tangle))))

(with-eval-after-load 'org-src
  (define-key org-src-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-v C-t") #'alec-tangle-from-org-src-buffer)
  (define-key org-src-mode-map (kbd "M-SPC o t") #'alec-tangle-from-org-src-buffer))
```

Explanation: I make sure I'm really in an Org Src buffer and said buffer is associated with a file. The source file name is in the variable `org-src-source-file-name`. I didn't verify this, but I believe it is required to save the source block you're editing for changes to be captured in the tangle. Then tangle using a `with-current-buffer` block. Works well enough for me!

I also included my keybindings for fun. I made sure `org-src` is loaded before trying to bind to `org-src-mode-map`.